# python if statement not working properly, whats wrong am I doing here?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.7

I'm trying to write a simple if statement but I don't know why it's not working, I'm using vscode and python extension tried to disable python extension and auto save in vscode to see if it what causes the problem but that didn't resolve the problem.

so I must be doing something wrong here is my code:

Not working if gold is found it returns true, but if diamonds found it returns false!

```
import re

cave = 'high qualaity diamonds have been found '

match = re.search(r'\bhigh\b\s\bqualaity\b', cave)


if match and ('gold' or 'diamonds') in cave:
   print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```

same as the above one:

```
if (match) and ('gold' or 'diamonds') in cave:
   print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```

Not working too always return True weather the word is found or not:

```
if match and 'gold' or 'diamonds' in cave:
   print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```

same as above:

```
if (match) and ('gold') or ('diamonds') in cave:
   print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```

Comment: 'gold' in cave or 'diamond' in cave ?

Comment: Didn't try that before but this worked thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

if you do this in python `('gold' or 'diamonds') in cave` this correspond  `'gold' in cave`

```
if match and ('gold' in cave or 'diamonds' in cave):
       print(True)
    else:
       print(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Felipe states in his reply. Using the "in cave" condition inside the brackets will solve your issue.

```
import re

cave = 'high quality diamonds have been found '

match = re.search(r'\bhigh\b\s\bquality\b', cave)


if match and ('gold' in cave or 'diamonds' in cave):
   print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using some more parenthesis can really save your life.**

Hope this helps:

```
import re

cave = 'high qualaity test have been found '

match = re.search(r'\bhigh\b\s\bqualaity\b', cave)

if match and (('gold' in cave) or ('diamonds' in cave)):
   print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```